# Prove: If $G$ has an element of order $k$ and an element of order $m$, the order of $G$ is a multiple of lcm(k,m).

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove: If $G$ has an element of order $k$ and an element of order $m$, the order of $G$ is a multiple of lcm(k,m).

This is the same as asking to show if $k\mid n$ and $m\mid n$ then $q \mid n$. Where $n$ is the order of $G$ and $q$ is the lcm(k,m). I can't show this. Any help

Comment: Assuming, of course, $\;G\;$ is finite.

Comment: @Timbuc Assuming the Axiom of Choice, no assumption of finitude is needed: every infinite cardinal number is divisible by every smaller number except zero.

Comment: I don't think that's the intention in this exercise, @bof. And I'm not sure whether from $\;\kappa \lambda=\lambda\;,\;\;\forall\,\kappa \le \lambda\;$ would be very accurate to say $\;\kappa\mid\lambda\;$ in the sense of number theory and for infinite cardinals...but I don't know much on this.

Comment: Yes, I left out $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_1$ be the subgroup of order $k$ and $g_2$ be the subgroup of order $m$. By Lagrange's theorem $|G|$ is a multiple of both $k$ and $m$ since $|\langle g_1 \rangle|=k$ and $|\langle g_2 \rangle|=m$.

Thus $|G|$ is a common multiple of $k$ and $m$ and therefore is divisible by the least common multiple of $k$ and $m$.

Comment: How do you know g1 and g2 are cyclic? And how can you switch from elements of G to subgroups of G?

Comment: @JohannFranklin We refer to subgroups, not elements, as cyclic. We can always form the cyclic subgroup generated by an element, and the order of this subgroup is the order of the element generating it.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Clever. Thanks.

Comment: By the theorem that says the order of any element of a finite group divides the order of the group, can we bypass the subgroups argument and just say since k divides the order of G and m divides the order of G, then the order of G is a common multiple of k and m and therefore lcm(k,m) divides the order of G?

Comment: Sure, but that theorem is usually proved via Lagrange.